# Resize file dimension in Linux

Tags: linux

I would like to resize a file in Linux, I need this:

- Duplicate file, my file now is 1gb and I want a 2gb file, so duplicate the numbers of rows.
- Truncate the file to a certain number of rows.

Comment: Both of those are pretty simple. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing I found truncate but I don't think it suits for me

Comment: `head -n foo` will take the first n lines of foo.  `cat foo foo > baz` will join two copies of foo as baz.